# Get Inner HTML from listing when its button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table of places that I'm listing, and a section where the places can be individually added to a list. When the button is clicked, it changes the innerHTML for the list items to the innerHTML of the result.

Each result has its own button, and I need the function to pull the right HTML based on the button that is clicked. I also need the script to switch the list item that it changes based on whether or not the previous list item has already been changed.

Right now I can only get the function to switch the html of the first list item to the html of the first result in my table. I need to be able to add three different items to my list when those three different buttons are clicked.

Here is my code so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <div class="row" align="center">
    <h2>Create a Dilly</h2>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="" id="placeaimg" width="80%"><br/>
    <p style='visibility: hidden;' id='placeaid'></p>
    <h3 id="placeaname">Place One Name</h3>
    <p id="placeaaddress">Place Address</p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4">
<img src="" id="placebimg" width="80%"><br/>
<p style='visibility: hidden;' id='placebid'></p>
<h3 id="placebname">Place Two Name</h3>
<p id="placebaddress">Place Address</p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4">
<img src="" id="placecimg" width="80%"><br/>
<p style='visibility: hidden;' id='placecid'></p>
<h3 id="placecname">Place Three Name</h3>
<p id="placecaddress">Place Address</p>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" href="dilly.php">Create</a>
</div>

<script>

function addToDilly(){

    document.getElementById("placeaid").innerHTML = document.getElementById("placeid").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("placeaname").innerHTML = document.getElementById("placename").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("placeaaddress").innerHTML = document.getElementById("placeaddress").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("placeaimg").src = document.getElementById("placeimg").src;
    }

</script>

 <table class="table table-striped">
<?php
$list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Places WHERE city='Houston' AND state='TX'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($list))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    echo "<div class='col-xs-4'>";
    echo "<p style='visibility: hidden;' id='placeid'>$row->id</p>";
    echo "<a href='place.php?id=$row->id'><img id='placeimg' src='$row->img' height='150px'></a><br/>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='col-xs-8'>";
    echo "<h3 id='placename'><strong><a href='place.php?id=$row->id'>$row->name</a></strong></h3>";
    echo "<p id='placeaddress'>$row->address</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='row'>&nbsp;</div>";
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    echo "<a class='btn btn-lg btn-warning' onclick='addToDilly()'>Add To Dilly</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
</table>
```

Comment: You are using same id for different elements , this may cause error.
i can give you answer in JQuery if you are ok to use it, BTW jQuery is fun and simple.

Comment: That would be awesome @anwerjunaid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but don't forget to call jquery to your page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
addToDilly = function(uniqId){

    $("#placeaid").html( $("#"+uniqId+" .placeid").html() );
    $("#placeaname").html( $("#"+uniqId+" .placename").html() );
    $("#placeaaddress").html( $("#"+uniqId+" .placeaddress").html() );
    $("#placeaimg").attr("src" , $("#"+uniqId+" .placeimg").attr("src") );
    }

});

</script>

 <table class="table table-striped">
<?php
$list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Places WHERE city='Houston' AND state='TX'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($list))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td id='row-$row->id'>"; // or some unique identifier to this row
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    echo "<div class='col-xs-4'>";
    echo "<p style='visibility: hidden;' class='placeid'>$row->id</p>";
    echo "<a href='place.php?id=$row->id'><img class='placeimg' src='$row->img' height='150px'></a><br/>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='col-xs-8'>";
    echo "<h3 class='placename'><strong><a href='place.php?id=$row->id'>$row->name</a></strong></h3>";
    echo "<p class='placeaddress'>$row->address</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='row'>&nbsp;</div>";
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    echo "<a class='btn btn-lg btn-warning' onclick='addToDilly(\'row-$row->id\')'>Add To Dilly</a>";// again pass that unique id to function
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
</table>
```

I have only changed your javascript and php code , please make sure those element exists where you going to assign new values.
Hope this will work.

Comment: It's not working for me. I made sure to call JQuery and even added `$row->id` to the front of the ids, but it the button's not working.

Comment: check the browser's console ,see what's the error is? paste that here.

Comment: You have to replace your javascript code with mine. You can check edited code.